# Codename one Connection Refused

Tags: codenameone, connection-refused

Quick question about Codename One. How would I handle a Connection Refused error? I have all the response listeners and they are overridden in the ConnectionRequest object, but when a connection refused error occurs it isn't going through my code and the application crashes. Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can override one of the error methods in `ConnectionRequest` to handle it for a specific connection e.g. `handleIOException`.

To do this globally you can use `NetworkManager`'s `addErrorListener`, just make sure to invoke `consume()` on the event object so it won't propagate onwards.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that `setFailSilently()` was set to true, when it needed to be false. This is why it did not fire properly.